# what is the difference between ActionContext and ValueStack in struts2

Tags: struts2, actioncontext

I am unable to understand how parameters go into ValueStack .
How the parameters are passed.

what is the use of value stack and ActionContext?

I am having a variable name with getter & setter in my Action class,where will be the values be stored.

Comment: Also, you should accept answers to your questions if you've found them to be useful(See there is a tick there)and also use upvotes. It will help you get more answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ActionContext is the context in which an Action is executed. Each context is basically a container of objects an action needs for execution like the session, parameters, locale, etc.

ValueStack - Contains all the application-domain–specific data for the request

Comment: just an addiction value stack in a virtual stack/container of the request/application specific data